# iOS swift4, Click multiple UITextFields，Keyboard show, the UIButton that has moved up does not know why it moved down

Tags: ios, swift

multiple `UITextField`, soft keyboard show and `UIButton` move up when click one `UITextField`.

keyboard closed when click on a blank area.

Now keyboard show, click another `UITextField`, `UIButton` move down, the keyboard still shows at this point, I don't want to let the `UIButton` move down.

Why `UIButton` move down when keyboard show?

**Gif Screen capture**

- click1: keyboard show
- click2: keyboard hide
- click3: keyboard show
- click4: keyboard show, but i don't want `UIButton` move down.
- Continue with click3 and click4, `UIButton` still underneath.
- Double click on a `UITextField`, the `UIButton` will move up from the new

[image: problem gif display]

Below is the code

```
class LoginPasswordViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneInput: UITextField! // this is the first UITextField
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordInput: UITextField! // this is the second UITextField
    @IBOutlet weak var btnOK: UIButton! // this is the UIButton, it move up when Soft keyboard show.
    fileprivate var btnOKOriginY: CGFloat!
    fileprivate var isShow: Bool?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // observer keyboard show
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil)

        // observer keyboard hide
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        btnOK.frame.origin.y = btnOKOriginY
        isShow = false
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            print("btnOK.frame.origin.y = ", btnOK.frame.origin.y)

            if  isShow ?? false && btnOK.frame.origin.y != btnOKOriginY{
                return
            }
            isShow = true
            if btnOKOriginY == nil {
                btnOKOriginY = btnOK.frame.origin.y
            }

            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
            btnOK.frame.origin.y = btnOKOriginY - keyboardHeight
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        closeSoftKey()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        closeSoftKey()
        return true
    }

    func closeSoftKey() {
        phoneInput.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordInput.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks wrong 'if  isShow ?? false && btnOK.frame.origin.y != btnOKOriginY', I think it should be == not !=

Comment: `btnOK.frame.origin.y != btnOKOriginY` means if is now `y` == btnOKOrignY, i need move up `btnOK`.

Comment: switch UITextField not call `keyboardWillHide` method. but `btnOK` has moved down

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton`'s initialization by `swift` code, the question no more...

Below is the code, other unchanged

```
var btnOK: UIButton!

func initUIButton() {

    btnOK = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 55 - 16,
                                   y: self.view.frame.height - 55 - 32,
                                   width: 55,
                                   height: 55))
    btnOK.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_next"), for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(btnOK)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    initUIButton()
}
```